# Get full source of a url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am aware that i can get the contents of the page with file_get_contents method,
But is there a way to get the source of everything that is between *script* tags?
i.e let's say that the page builds an object that i want to get a hold of:

```
 <script src="js.js">
  dataLayer = [{dest":"Lithuania","type" : "small", "code" : "4"}];
 </script>
```

is there any way i can get the contents with php or any other method?

Comment: What do you mean by "*everything that is in between*"?

Comment: use `DOMDocument` in `php`. to get contents between specific tags.

Comment: "*is there any way i can get the contents...?*" Yes, yes there is.

Comment: Use preg_match_all or DOMDocument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all script tags inside and HTML document with regular expressions.

Here just some php lines to retrieve all script tags:

```
$matches = array();
$pattern = '/<script[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/script>/ius';
$subject = file_get_contents('YOUR URL');
preg_match_all( $pattern, $subject , $matches );
```

Here *$matches* is an array which contains all string matching the pattern. The key 0 contain complete pattern match and the key 1 contain only the match group between () :

```
[
  0 => [
    0 => "<script>script content 1</script>",
    1 => "<script>script content 2</script>",
    ...
  ],
  1 => [
    0 => "script content 1",
    1 => "script content 2",
    ...
  ]
]
```

Some details on functions:

- preg_match_all: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php
- Regular expression in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php

I hope this help :)